# Python Pandas: Multi Indexed columns DataFrame merging task

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append, multi-index

I have a task to merge all sub-dfs to Master df. Below is master_df with only columns (Multi-Index)

```
master_df:
first        bar                 baz                 foo   
second       one       two       thr       fou       fiv       six
```

So in master_df, level=0 columns is 'first' and level=1 columns is 'second'. And my task is to add values to this dataframe (appending each row)

My data_dfs are below

```
data_df1:
    one     two
a   1.23    2.23
b   3.41    0.23

data_df2:
    fiv     six
a   3.13    4.25
b   1.42    NaN
```

Noticed that data_df1 and data_df2 have single level columns that matches level=1 ('second' column in master_df). And I need to make my two data dfs values to merge in my Master_df.

```
master_df:  #after the merge
first        bar                 baz                 foo   
second       one       two       thr       fou       fiv       six  
a           1.23      2.23       NaN       NaN      3.13      4.25
b           3.41      0.23       NaN       NaN      1.42       NaN
```

Since all my 'second' columns (level=1) in master_df are unique, I only need to match names to put each values in. Is this possible without making Multi-index columns for each of my data_dfs? Please help me out. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) + [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
mux = master_df.columns
df = pd.concat([data_df1,data_df2], axis=1).reindex(columns=mux, level=1)
print (df)
first    bar       baz       foo      
second   one   two thr fou   fiv   six
a       1.23  2.23 NaN NaN  3.13  4.25
b       3.41  0.23 NaN NaN  1.42   NaN
```

Data from `master_df` not exist in joined `DataFrames`, so need [`append`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) them:

```
print (master_df)
first  bar     baz     foo    
second one two thr fou fiv six
0        0   4   5   6   8   7
1        4   5   8   7   1   2

df = (pd.concat([data_df1,data_df2], axis=1).reindex(columns=master_df.columns, level=1)
        .append(master_df, ignore_index=True))
print (df)
first    bar        baz        foo      
second   one   two  thr  fou   fiv   six
0       1.23  2.23  NaN  NaN  3.13  4.25
1       3.41  0.23  NaN  NaN  1.42   NaN
2       0.00  4.00  5.0  6.0  8.00  7.00
3       4.00  5.00  8.0  7.0  1.00  2.00
```

Comment: One question. What if my master_df have a few rows of data and I need to append master_df with my data_df values? would this work as well?

Comment: Data are lost, so need append them by `df = pd.concat([data_df1,data_df2], axis=1).reindex(columns=mux, level=1).append(master_df, ignore_index=True)`

Comment: Thanks!. Last question, would it work as same for pd.Series for my datas?

Comment: Can you explain more? Because Series have no columns ;)